# How to immutably update/replace React Redux State with a double nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

My redux state has a SessionList which is an array of SessionObjects, and each SessionObject has an array of HandObjects.

I use state to update individual SessionObjects by adding new HandObjects, however I want to update the redux store with my updated SessionObject (immutably, if possible).

the index of the SessionObject within SessionList is action.payload.Id (I think? i will show my SessionObject constructor)

**Adding Sessions works just fine, and I only update a Session with the session already in the store

I have tried every link that I can find, but my code is just different enough that I can't seem to update my SessionList correctly.

my reducer, with the initial state
store.js (where my reducers are)

```
const initialState = {
    SessionList: [],
}
...
case "UPDATE_SESSION":
            //action.payload is a SessionObject
            //action.payload.Id is the Id that i want to update
            // i want to set SessionList[action.payload.Id] = action.payload
            state = {
                ...state,
                SessionList : state.SessionList.map((item, index) => {
                    if (index != action.payload.id) {
                      return item
                    }

                    return action.payload
                    //This code doesn't visibly do anything that I can find
                  })

                // *******FIRST TRY*******
                // ...state,
                //  SessionList: {
                //     ...state.SessionList,
                //     SessionList[action.payload.id] : action.payload 
//syntax error, but basically what i want to do
                //      }
                // }
                // ***********************
            };
            break;
```

SessionObject constructor
Session.js

```
export function SessionObject(_id, _name, _hands) {
    this.id = _id, //int
    this.name = _name, //string
    this.HandList = _hands //array of HandObject objects
}
var defaultSession = new SessionObject(0, "default", []);
```

*in case i am doing this wrong, 
I call 
(Session.js)

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.updateMethod(this.state.Session); //update store
```

from a stack-navigator child component.
then in the parent component,
I call 
(Home.js)

```js
UpdateSession = (session) => {
      this.props.updateSession(session);
    };
```

With my dispatcher looking like:
(Home.js)

```
updateSession: (session) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "UPDATE_SESSION",
          payload: session
        });
      }
```

From testing, I am somewhat sure my reducer is getting called correctly.

I want to replace the SessionObject with action.payload in the correct index of the SessionList.

**EDIT** *

Session.js

```
addItem = () => {
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
        Session : {
          ...state,
          HandList: [...state.Session.HandList, new HandObject(state.HandCount)]
        },
        HandCount : state.HandCount + 1,
        }));
        this.props.navigation.state.params.updateMethod(this.state.Session); //update store
    };
```

The state in Session.js is a SessionObject

Comment: Where are you creating the `session` provided to `updateSession`? There's a possibility that you're passing the same reference over and over? I.e., if you try with 

```
payload: { ...session }
```

the issue persists?

Comment: @sminutoli I added the code in my question, where I am updating a Session.  I thought that the way I do it would create a new object? In terms of my workflow, my home screen accesses the redux store, and places the SessionList (full of SessionObjects) in a FlatList.  Each of these is a button, which navigates to a Session page, which shows a singular SessionObject's list of HandObjects in the same way.  The Hands are added/updated, which updates the SessionObject in the state of Session.js, which sends the session back to the Home screen, updating the redux store with the complete structure.

Comment: `setState` isn't a synchronous call, you can't use `this.state.Session` expecting it being the brand new object, maybe you could store this new session on a variable, passing both `setState` and `updateMethod` the same object. I'm not understanding why you mix redux w setState anyway.

Comment: The SessionObject constructor uses a lowercase "i" for its `id` property, while in the   `UPDATE_SESSION` case of the reducer, `action.payload.Id` (uppercase "I") is written, which would evaluate as `undefined.` Is that what you're seeing if you log `action.payload`?

Comment: @leitdeux good catch, however that didn't change the result

Comment: @sminutoli I am combining them because I need to update and add HandObjects within each SessionObject, and store all of them in redux.  I could do all of that in Redux, but since State implementation is already coded, I was just going to leave it.  I am using both so that so I can later use Redux-Persist to easily persist my data once the application is more complete. Each HandObject and SessionObject needs to be edit-able, so i thought that replacing the object is much easier than updating it.  The objects will have more attributes in the future.

Comment: I had just thought it would be a better structure for this small app to just pass a SessionObject as props to a Session screen, and then HandObjects to Hand screens, as opposed to being able to access the entire store when only ONE specific session is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve a result of `SessionList[action.payload.Id]`, you need to initialise `SessionList` as an object and not an array. Then you can update accordingly.

```
   const initialState = {
      SessionList: {},
   }

   case "UPDATE_SESSION":
            state = {
                ...state,
                SessionList: Object.keys(state.SessionList).reduce((acc, id) => {
                    if (id === action.payload.Id) {
                      acc[id] = action.payload;
                    } else {
                      acc[id] = state.SessionList[id];
                    }

                    return acc;
                  }, {});
            };
```

**Update**

As requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535651/how-to-immutably-update-replace-react-redux-state-with-a-double-nested-array-of/56535739#comment99655288_56535739), following are the *add*, *update*, *replace* and *delete* handlers without changing `SessionList` to an object.

```
const initialState = {
     SessionList: [],
}
```

**Note:** `action.payload` (wherever used) is a session object.

*Add*

```
state = {
    ...state,
    SessionList: [...state.SessionList, action.payload];
};
```

*Update*

```
state = {
    ...state,
    SessionList: state.SessionList.map((session) => {
        if (session.Id === action.payload.Id) {
           return Object.assign({}, session, action.payload);
        }

        return session;
    })
};
```

*Replace*

```
state = {
    ...state,
    SessionList: state.SessionList.map((session) => {
        if (session.Id === action.payload.Id) {
           return action.payload;
        }

        return session;
    })
};
```

*Delete*

```
state = {
    ...state,
    SessionList: state.SessionList.filter((session) => session.Id !== action.payload.Id)
};
```

Comment: Objects dont have `.reduce`, I understand your intent but its innacurate

Comment: @sminutoli You are right. I am habitual of using `lodash.reduce` that also works on objects. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @UmairSarfraz is there a way to do this with an array? My structure doesn't work with a SessionList object.  The SessionList holds an array of SessionObjects, which each hold an array of HandObjects.  I need to be able to add/delete/update/replace each respective object in all levels of my structure

Comment: @AdamWells Yes. I have updated my answer. Please check. Hope that answers your question. If you need any clarification, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @UmairSarfraz That is very helpful thank you! However I am starting to think that my problem might be elsewhere in my app.  In my Session.js file, I am creating HandObjects which are supposed to be added to the SessionObject in it's Hands array, and when i navigate back to the SessionList in Home.js, and then navigate back to the Session.js file, the HandObjects that I created beforehand should still be there, however it deletes them.

Comment: @AdamWells Not sure I understand the issue. Would be good if you create a new question for this issue.